# Unknown Formal Identifier in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, hdl, modelsim

I am facing an error with my VHDL code. I am new in it. After putting so much of my time I am even unable to resolve this error. I am using ModelSim software for it. Here is my code:

```
-- Insert library and use clauses
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Begin entity declaration for top-level "mult8x8"
ENTITY mult8x8 IS
-- Begin port declartion
PORT (
    -- Declare control inputs "clk", "start" and "reset_a"
    clk, start, reset_a : IN STD_LOGIC;

    -- Declare data inputs "dataa" and "datab"
    dataa, datab : IN UNSIGNED(7 DOWNTO 0);

    -- Declare multiplier output "product8x8_out"
    product8x8_out : OUT UNSIGNED(15 DOWNTO 0);

    -- Declare seven segment display outputs
    seg_a, seg_b, seg_c, seg_d, seg_e, seg_f, seg_g, done_flag : OUT 
    STD_LOGIC
);

   -- End entity
   END ENTITY mult8x8;

   ARCHITECTURE logic OF mult8x8 IS

-- Declare all lower level components
COMPONENT adder
    PORT (  
        dataa, datab : IN UNSIGNED (15 DOWNTO 0);
        sum : OUT UNSIGNED (15 DOWNTO 0)
          );
END COMPONENT adder;

 ---##################################################  
 -- complete component instantiations
 -- the components were created in the prior labs
 --- ############### ----

COMPONENT mult4x4
    PORT(
        dataa, datab : IN UNSIGNED(3 DOWNTO 0);
        product : OUT UNSIGNED(7 DOWNTO 0)
        );
END COMPONENT mult4x4;

COMPONENT mux4
    PORT(
        mux_in_a, mux_in_b: IN UNSIGNED(3 DOWNTO 0);
        mux_sel : IN STD_LOGIC;
        mux_out : OUT UNSIGNED(3 DOWNTO 0)
        );
END COMPONENT mux4;

COMPONENT shifter
        Port ( 
            input: IN UNSIGNED (7 DOWNTO 0);
        shift_cntrl : IN UNSIGNED (1 DOWNTO 0);
        shift_out : OUT UNSIGNED (15 DOWNTO 0)
        );
END COMPONENT shifter;

COMPONENT counter
    PORT (
        clk, aclr_n : IN STD_LOGIC;
        count_out : OUT UNSIGNED (1 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END COMPONENT counter;

COMPONENT mult_control
    PORT (
        clk, reset_a, start : IN STD_LOGIC;
        count : IN UNSIGNED (1 DOWNTO 0);
        input_sel, shift_sel : OUT UNSIGNED(1 DOWNTO 0);
        state_out : OUT UNSIGNED(2 DOWNTO 0);
        done, clk_ena, sclr_n : OUT STD_LOGIC
    );
END COMPONENT mult_control; 

COMPONENT seven_segment_cntrl
    Port ( input : in  UNSIGNED (2 downto 0);
               seg_a : out  STD_LOGIC;
               seg_b : out  STD_LOGIC;
               seg_c : out  STD_LOGIC;
               seg_d : out  STD_LOGIC;
               seg_e : out  STD_LOGIC;
               seg_f : out  STD_LOGIC;
               seg_g : out  STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT seven_segment_cntrl;

COMPONENT reg16
    Port(
        clk, clk_ena, sclr_n : IN STD_LOGIC;
        datain: IN UNSIGNED (15 DOWNTO 0);
        reg_out : OUT UNSIGNED (15 DOWNTO 0)
        );
END COMPONENT  reg16; 
--- ############### ----


-- Declare internal signals to use as wires to connect blocks
-- used these signals to connect up all the components
-- you should not need anymore signals
---
SIGNAL aout, bout : UNSIGNED(3 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL product : UNSIGNED(7 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL shift_out, sum, product8x8 : UNSIGNED(15 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL count, shift : UNSIGNED(1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL state_out : UNSIGNED(2 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL clk_ena, sclr_n, start_n : std_logic;
SIGNAL sel : UNSIGNED(1 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN
-- Start SIGNAL requires inversion before connecting to counter
start_n <= not(start);

-- Connect blocks per schematic in the lab manual
-- this port map is completed
u1: mux4 PORT MAP (mux_in_a => dataa(3 DOWNTO 0), 
                   mux_in_b => dataa(7 DOWNTO 4), 
                   mux_sel => sel(0),
                   mux_out => aout(3 DOWNTO 0));


u2: mux4 PORT MAP (mux_in_a => dataa(3 DOWNTO 0), 
                   mux_in_b => dataa(7 DOWNTO 4), 
                   mux_sel => sel(0),
                   mux_out => aout(3 DOWNTO 0));

u3: mult4x4 PORT MAP (aout => dataa (3 DOWNTO 0),
              bout => datab (3 DOWNTO 0),
                   product => product(7 DOWNTO 0));

u4: shifter PORT MAP (product => input (7 DOWNTO 0),
                shift => shift_cntrl (1 DOWNTO 0),
                shift_out => shift_out (15 DOWNTO 0));

u5: counter PORT MAP (clk => clk, 
              start => aclr_n,
                count => count_out (1 DOWNTO 0));

u6: mult_control PORT MAP (clk => clk, 
               reset_a => reset_a, 
               start => start,
               count => count (1 DOWNTO 0),
                sel => input_sel (1 DOWNTO 0), 
                shift => shift_sel (1 DOWNTO 0),
                state_out => state_out (2 DOWNTO 0),
                done => done, 
                clk_ena => clk_ena, 
                sclr_n => sclr_n);

u7: reg16 PORT MAP (clk => clk, 
            clk_era => clk_ena, 
            sclr_n => sclr_n,
            sum => datain (15 DOWNTO 0),
                product8x8 => reg_out (15 DOWNTO 0));


u8: adder PORT MAP (shift_out => dataa (15 DOWNTO 0), 
            product8x8 => datab (15 DOWNTO 0),
                sum => sum (15 DOWNTO 0));



u9: seven_segment_cntrl PORT MAP (state_out => input (2 downto 0),
                    seg_a => seg_a,
                    seg_b => seg_b,
                    seg_c => seg_c,
                    seg_d => seg_d,
                    seg_e => seg_e,
                    seg_f => seg_f,
                    seg_g => seg_g);



product8x8_out <= product8x8;

-- End architecture
END ARCHITECTURE logic;
```

Let me attched the errors that I am facing so that it will be easy to help me regarding this.

> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(151): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "aout".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(152): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "bout".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(155): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "input".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(156): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "shift_cntrl".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(155): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "product".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(156): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "shift".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(160): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "aclr_n".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(161): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "count_out".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(160): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "start".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(161): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "count".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(167): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "input_sel".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(168): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "shift_sel".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(170): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "done".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(167): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "sel".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(168): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "shift".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(177): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "datain".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(178): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "reg_out".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(175): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "clk_era".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(177): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "sum".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(178): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "product8x8".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(181): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "shift_out".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(182): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "product8x8".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(187): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "input".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(187): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier "state_out".
>
> ** Error: E:/Fiverr/VHDL/VHDLCounterMultiplier/ModelSimdo/mult8x8.vhd(201): VHDL Compiler exiting

Kindly help me to resolve the errors. I will be very thankful to you and it will be really appreciable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as just one example, on line 134, you instantiate a multiplier:

```
u3: mult4x4 PORT MAP (aout => dataa (3 DOWNTO 0),
                      bout => datab (3 DOWNTO 0),
                      product => product(7 DOWNTO 0));
```

Where your port map identifies a formal called `aout`.

Yet, if we look up the component on line 42, we find:

```
COMPONENT mult4x4
    PORT(
        dataa, datab : IN UNSIGNED(3 DOWNTO 0);
        product : OUT UNSIGNED(7 DOWNTO 0)
        );
END COMPONENT mult4x4;
```

Obviously, the formal parameters are `dataa` and `datab`, not `aout` and `bout`. This is what the first error message is talking about.

Note that in a `port map`, the syntax is always *<formal port>* => *<signal>*, regardless of whether it's an input port or an output port. You seem to be reversing them for input ports for some reason. The arrow symbolizes the mapping, not the flow of the signals.